# Preventing unintended CRUD actions in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, roles

To give some context on what I know. I learn some time ago from this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kfBvS-VOZFw&list=PL6n9fhu94yhVm6S8I2xd6nYz2ZORd7X2v&index=19) even when you set a field from your model `READ ONLY` on the View how easy is use tools like [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to alter the POST data and change the value.

[image]

What you do in this case is use Model Binding to specify the list of fields you want Edit and ignore the rest

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Edit")]
public ActionResult Edit_Post(int id)
{
    EmployeeBusinessLayer employeeBusinessLayer = new EmployeeBusinessLayer();

    Employee employee = employeeBusinessLayer.Employees.Single(x => x.ID == id);
    UpdateModel(employee, new string[] { "ID", "Gender", "City", "DateOfBirth" });
                                             ^^^ Name isnt updated
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        employeeBusinessLayer.SaveEmployee(employee);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(employee);
}
```

Now I learn about Authentication using `AspNet.Identity`.

- Can check if user isn't authenticated to send him to the Login page.
- If user belong to certain `Role`, I can show personalized menus.
- Or check the list of contacts for the user and show only those.

But even if you filter the list of contacts based on the `user_id` before create the view you can access the actions `EDIT` and `DELETE` using links like this.

```
  http://MVCDemo/Employee/Edit/1
  http://MVCDemo/Employee/Delete/1
```

And as long you are authenticated, you can change other users data.

So, **how you integrate authentication with CRUD actions to avoid unintended actions?**

Seem to me to solve this situation I have to apply something similar to the Model Binding example. When get and `Edit` or `Delete` post request, first get the `Employee` from the DB using the `id` and compare if belong to the current user.

But that create a lot of repeats code across all the functions.

So what is the right way to handle this?

**EDIT**

To try to make it clear. Lets assume I have an address book application. Each user have contacts:

```
 contact_id    user_id     name    phone ....
      1          1          A
      2          1          B
      3          1          C
      4          2          D
      5          2          E
      6          2          F
```

The action to show contacts use authenticated `user_id` to filter the contacts before send it to the view.

Then you have an Edit/Delete actions where you get `contact_id` and process to Update/Delete. Even when both users have permission to these actions they shouldn't be able to affect other users contacts. But as I explain is very easy change the page using a tool like fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

I can only speak from personal experience but I don't know any MVC features for managing this for you; I've only ever taken the approach you outline of retrieving the data model from the database and explicitly writing the logic to check if the current user has permissions to modify this resource, returning a 401 error if not.

Comment: The problem isnt authorize. `UserA` can edit `EmployessA` but `UserB` can only edit `EmployessB`

Comment: Ah I understand now, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the incoming request userid with the userid you have in the session, encrypted cookie or web tokens like jwt which ever you use.

Usually if i have load balancer i use encrypted cookie where i store the logged in user's id and compare it with the id i am getting from the request. if both match, update/delete profile else return Unauthorized.

Same can be done in case of Session or tokens as well.

Comment: But in this case the `user_id` is the same the problem is you can change the post data and use a different `employee_id` not associated with that `user_id`. Lets say you have a contacts list. You can delete your contacts but you can't delete other users contact.

Comment: since the user_id is going to be encrypted, no other user can pretend to be another user. You need to map the contact list with the user_id who has access to it. If the user is meddling with the post data, he can do it only for his own contact, since you will be checking to see if the user is mapped  to that contact and if so delete it else return unauthorized